# Recargar/Reiniciar reCAPTCHA de Google

Tags: jquery, ajax, captcha

Estoy realizando un formulario para envió de mensajes desde mi pagina web, la cual la estoy haciendo con `jquery` y `ajax`, usando el `reCAPTCHA` de Google con índica el titulo.

Los mensaje se envian correctamente, pero la cuestión está en que al enviar el email el `reCAPTCHA` **queda marcado como válido**, a pesar de que reinicio el formulario. Estuve utilizando la siguiente instrucción `grecaptcha.reload();` pero no tiene ningún efecto.

Mi código:

```
 $.ajax({
            beforeSend:function(){
                init_load();
            },
            url: base_url+'site/send_email',
            type:'POST',
            cache:false,
            data: formData,
            success:function(response){

                end_load();

                if(response.trim() === 'success'){
                    $('#form-send-message')[0].reset(this);
                    grecaptcha.reload();
                    end_load_message('Gracias Tu Mensaje Fue Enviado Correctamente');

                }else if(response.trim() === 'error-c'){

                    load_alert('Comprueba que no eres un Robots');

                }else{
                    grecaptcha.reload();
                    load_message_error('Tu Mensaje No Pudo Ser Enviado Intente Nuevamente');
                }

            }

        });
```

Comment: Intenta con ``grecaptcha.reset();``

Comment: fino me sirvió mucho! gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Debes utilizar el método **.reset()** del Google reCAPTCHA.

```
grecaptcha.reset();
```

## [Documentación](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#js_api) de Google reCAPTCHA:

> **grecaptcha.reset(opt_widget_id
>   )**
>
> Resets the reCAPTCHA widget.
>   opt_widget_id
>     Optional widget ID, defaults to the first widget created if unspecified.

Traducción:

> Reinicia el widget de reCAPTCHA.
>   **opt_widget_id** *Opcional* ID del widget, por predefinido toma el primer widget que se creó.